# Angular Service object undefined in Component

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components, angular-httpclient, angular-observable

I am using Angular 4 CLI project and I have angular service, angular component, interceptor, guard and other regular items.

My Angular service component has following item:

```
export class AdminAuthService {
   adminAuthContext: AdminAuthContext;
   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private urlService: UrlService) {
      ... other code ...
      this.loadSecurityContext();
   }

   loadSecurityContext() {
    this.httpClient.get<AdminAuthContext>(`${this.urlService.url_authContext}`)
        .subscribe(context => {
            this.adminAuthContext = context;
        }, error => Utils.logErrorResponse(error));
    }
}
```

My Component has following code:

```
export class ArticleManagerComponent{
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private articleService: ArticleService, private adminAuthService: AdminAuthService) {
   }
   isAdmin() {
      let canActivate = this.adminAuthService.adminAuthContext && this.adminAuthService.adminAuthContext.claims && (this.adminAuthService.adminAuthContext.claims.find(claim =>  claim.type === 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' && claim.value === 'Admin'));
      return canActivate;
   }
}
```

Now, I have Component.Html

```
<div class="rightpane" *ngIf="isAdmin()">
<admin-article-edit [selectedArticleId]="articleEdit_articleId"></admin-article-edit>
```

Now, I call AdminAuthServie through my Login component and make sure that I have aminAuthContext object set.

Now, I call Article component and It call isAdmin method where I am getting AdminAuthContext undefined.

Can anyone tell why? and How to fix this?

Comment: Seeing as `loadSecurityContext` is asynchronous, are you sure that it has completed by the time you call `isAdmin`?

Comment: yes, I am. before I call the IsAdmin, I debug (in vs code) and confirm that while service method called loadsecuritycontext I have breakpoint where It set my context variable and it hit and set it correctly. but when component is getting called, that service object gives undefined for the same variable.

Comment: And if you continue from that breakpoint, you still see the error? Sounds like the 2 components may be using separate instances of the service then

Comment: may be possible but how can we confirm?

Comment: How do you provide the services? In a module? Which module? Or have you added it to the `providers` array in each component?

Comment: Please post a https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: looks like It's due to the case sensitivity. I have aspnet core and it's pascal casing json by default. but in angular I have same class and object, it's camel casing. I have changed the aspnet core default json configuration serialization to use camel case and it started working. However I have another issue (little bit similar) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134624/angular-guard-is-not-able-to-access-the-angular-service-object

I have checked all the casing and everything looks ok here (same project so, it should work but it's not working) if anyone case suggest why?