# Angular Guard is not able to access the Angular Service Object

Tags: angularjs-scope, angular-services, angular-guards, angular-auth-oidc-client

I am trying to access the Angular Service Object (I have set the AuthContext in service) but Angular Guard is giving undefined even though that is well set.

I have login component, which I call first and internally It uses the Angular Auth Service.
In the constructor of that service, I ensure that AuthContext is well set. 
Through the debug, I have seen that object is available with all the required claims.

But then when I access the regular component (which I have guarded through the Auth Guard) CanActivate method in that Guard fails to access the context.

Any idea why?
Here is little overview of my code...

[image]

[image]

I also have tried to use the console log and it looks like Auth Guard called before the service class.
But Auth.Guard, I have used authservice in constructor and by virtue of Dependency injection, Service object should get called..
Don't know what's wrong here...

Here is console log 
[image]

any suggestion?